# Is there a R way to apply a custom function to all vector elements?

Tags: r, function, sequence, montecarlo

I've got this function which computes a `Monte Carlo` simulation for the probability of picking the same days of the year for `n` days:

```
monte_carlo <- function(n, repetition = 10000) {
  same_day <- replicate(repetition, {
    days <- sample(1:365, n, replace = TRUE)
    any(duplicated(days))
  })
  mean(same_day)
}
```

I want to compute the probabilities for a sequence of `n`, but this doesn't work, as it prints 0:

```
n <- seq(1, 50)
monte_carlo(n)
[1] 0
```

While for a standard R function it does work:

```
n <- seq(1, 50)
sqrt(n)
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 ...
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same results the `R way` (without using a `for` loop)?

Comment: `sapply(1:50, monte_carlo)`.

Comment: I believe your first question should be how you can calculate the probability of having any duplicates in your sample. When you have that probability, you can simply use `rbinom` instead of your function.

Comment: Btw. all other comments show use of loops. There is no real advantage over a `for` loop if you use these.

Comment: @RuiBarradas With `sapply` it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: See also [this Mathematics SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397371/what-is-the-probability-of-having-d-duplicates-when-sampling-n-elements-from).

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'll do, thanks.